# AngularJS ng-repeat not getting data from crontoller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to do an ng-repeat inside a div in a `<section>` in `index.html` but the values in my controller is not been evaluated.

module:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc overview
 * @description
 *
 * Main module of the application.
 */
angular
  .module('myModule', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'mainCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'main'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

controller:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @description
 * # mainCtrl
 */
angular.module('myModule')
  .controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    var rndNumber = Math.random() * 10;
    var rndMetros = Math.random() * 100;

    $scope.imoveis = {
      'desc': 'Casa Residencial',
      'end': 'Villa Formosa',
      'cidade': 'Campo Grande/SP',
      'img': '../../images/thumb-imovel.png',
      'random': rndNumber,
      'metrosUtil': rndMetros,
      'metrosTotal': rndMetros
    }, {
      'desc': 'Casa Residencial',
      'end': 'Villa Formosa',
      'cidade': 'Campo Grande/SP',
      'img': '../../images/thumb-imovel.png',
      'random': rndNumber,
      'metrosUtil': rndMetros,
      'metrosTotal': rndMetros
    }, {
      'desc': 'Casa Residencial',
      'end': 'Villa Formosa',
      'cidade': 'Campo Grande/SP',
      'img': '../../images/thumb-imovel.png',
      'random': rndNumber,
      'metrosUtil': rndMetros,
      'metrosTotal': rndMetros
    }, {
      'desc': 'Casa Residencial',
      'end': 'Villa Formosa',
      'cidade': 'Campo Grande/SP',
      'img': '../../images/thumb-imovel.png',
      'random': rndNumber,
      'metrosUtil': rndMetros,
      'metrosTotal': rndMetros
    }, {
      'desc': 'Casa Residencial',
      'end': 'Villa Formosa',
      'cidade': 'Campo Grande/SP',
      'img': '../../images/thumb-imovel.png',
      'random': rndNumber,
      'metrosUtil': rndMetros,
      'metrosTotal': rndMetros
    }, {
      'desc': 'Casa Residencial',
      'end': 'Villa Formosa',
      'cidade': 'Campo Grande/SP',
      'img': '../../images/thumb-imovel.png',
      'random': rndNumber,
      'metrosUtil': rndMetros,
      'metrosTotal': rndMetros
    };
  })
```

index.html (shortened):

```
<body ng-repeat="imovel in imoveis">
<section>
    <div class="imovel-thumb-container">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-3 card" ng-repeat="imovel in imoveis">
              <img class="card-img-top" ng-src="{{imovel.img}}" alt="imagem do imóvel resultante da busca">

              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="card-title">
                  <h4 class=".card-text"><span>{{imovel.desc}}</span> -{{imovel.end}}</h4>
                </div>
                <h5 class=".card-text">{{imovel.cidade}}</h5>

                <div class="card-ico-container">
                  <div class="ico-banheira">
                    <span>{{imovel.random}}</span><img src="../images/ico-banheira.png">
                  </div>
                  <div class="ico-solteiro">
                    <span>{{imovel.random}}</span><img src="../images/ico-solt.png">
                  </div>
                  <div class="ico-casal">
                    <span>{{imovel.random}}</span><img src="../images/ico-casal.png">
                  </div>
                  <div class="ico-garagem">
                    <span>{{imovel.random}}</span><img src="../images/ico-garagem.png">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="metros-container">
                  <div class="mts-util">
                    {{imovel.metrosUtil}}
                  </div>
                  <div class="mts-total">
                    {{imovel.metrosTotal}}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  </body>
```

The `imoveis:{}` objects are intended to be all the same.
I'm new to AngularJS and I don't know what I'm doing wrong, even though I googled for it and, for what I saw, my code is according to what I searched (although does have the possibility that I can be wrong).

In addition I wanted to ask one more question:

I tried to use scope isolation function in my controller, but the js linter that I'm using threw me errors:

```
(function() {
  angular.module('myModule')
  .controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {
  // controller logic
})();
```

What I did wrong?

Sorry for so much code and questions.

Comment: you shouldn't put `ng-controller="mainCtrl"` on the same div as `ng-repeat="imovel in imoveis"`, or it will create multiple instances of your controller

Comment: it looks like you are mixing `controllerAs`.

Comment: Your syntax for `imoveis` is invalid. This should be array, you need to wrap these objects into `[]`

Comment: Thank you @Aleksey Solovey. Fixed that in the edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have did mistakes to declare an array of object.

ng-repeat works only in array.

so you should declare your data like this:

```
$scope.imoveis = [
{
  'desc': 'Casa Residencial',
  'end': 'Villa Formosa',
  'cidade': 'Campo Grande/SP',
  'img': '../../images/thumb-imovel.png',
  'random': rndNumber,
  'metrosUtil': rndMetros,
  'metrosTotal': rndMetros
}, {
  'desc': 'Casa Residencial',
  'end': 'Villa Formosa',
  'cidade': 'Campo Grande/SP',
  'img': '../../images/thumb-imovel.png',
  'random': rndNumber,
  'metrosUtil': rndMetros,
  'metrosTotal': rndMetros
}
]
```

Comment: @barbsan By all heavens man! It did the trick. How could you tell that just in a few seconds? I'm trying to fix it for hours. If I had dollars I would pay you a cup of coffee. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the fact that you use the `ng-controller` directive combined with `ng-repeat`.

Instead, move the `ng-repeat` directive into a child element:

```
<div class="col-md-3 card" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="imovel in imoveis">
  </div>
</div>
```

You also have errors in your controller code. There is a syntax error in your `imoveis` variable declaration. You've probably missed the `[` and `]` for declaring an array.

```
$scope.imoveis = [{
  'desc': 'Casa Residencial',
  'end': 'Villa Formosa',
  'cidade': 'Campo Grande/SP',
  'img': '../../images/thumb-imovel.png',
  'random': rndNumber,
  'metrosUtil': rndMetros,
  'metrosTotal': rndMetros
}, ...]
```

Comment: Thank for the tip pal. Moved `ng-controller` directive to the `<body>`.